# Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Image::_checkMemory

Tags: magento-1.7, catalog, image

Looking at slow requests in newrelic for a product listing page the top function called was Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Image::_checkMemory() which does a bunch of stuff like checking the ini settings for memory_limit (`ini_get('memory_limit')`, checks the image size and calculates the memory needed for that and so on...

I've just added a `return true` (skip the checks, Magento has enough memory for those processes) in that function and the graph below shows the impact.

Anyone else did anything about this? Ideas, risks?

[image]

Comment: Did the same thing, no problem I'm aware of unless the store admins start uploading monster image files.

Comment: I've done this exact thing! No adverse effects that I've witnessed so far.

Comment: Shall we submit a patch to Magento? :)

Comment: A patch for Magento 2 to make it configurable would be nice. Defaulting it to "check memory limit" wouldn't break the shop for users in limited environments as Alan mentions below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other than the usual caveats about *you'll need to merge these changes with upgrades yourself*, there doesn't appear toe anything in those methods that changes PHP or Magento state in a significant way.  They appears to be there strictly to help users who are running Magento in a memory limited environment to avoid PHP crashes.